# Failed to instantiate one or more classes error in android studio because of which the design isn't displayed

Tags: java, android, android-layout, gradle, build.gradle

I am facing problems with my layout in android studio which is not being displayed because of an error called "Failed to instantiate one or more classes." I'm also facing an error in my build.gradle app module file whose error message is shown below.

I am new to android studio and I tried whatever I could on my part but I seem to be getting nowhere. Please let me know if you have a solution.

- I have tried changing my compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to a lower version in build.gradle app module i.e. from 28 to 26 which didn't work.
- I have also tried cleaning the project followed by invalidating/restarting.
- I have tried rebuilding the project too.

**My gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "naik.dattaraj.meme2"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        //exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' // This line shows the below mentioned error message
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:18.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation files('libs/CircleImageView-master/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar')
    implementation 'com.shitij.goyal:slide-button:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.github.shts:StoriesProgressView:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.pwittchen:swipe-rx2:0.3.0'
    implementation 'com.tomer:fadingtextview:2.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.8.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.leanback:leanback:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha09'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0-alpha09'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha09'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0-alpha09'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.databinding:library:3.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.databinding:databinding-common:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.databinding:adapters:3.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.databinding:databinding-adapters:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.3.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

**I get the following error message in my design view:**

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)  Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom
>   views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this
>   is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then
>   manually refresh the layout.  Exception Details
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ScaleType FIT_XY not supported.
>     at
>   de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.setScaleType(CircleImageView.java:134)
>     at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:203)   at
>   android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:172)   at
>   de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.(CircleImageView.java:98)
>     at
>   de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.(CircleImageView.java:94)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:866)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:866)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:866)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)

**And I get this error message in my build.gradle app module file:**

> Dependencies using groupId com.android.support and androidx.* can not
>   be combined but found
>   IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='com.android.support',
>   myArtifactId='support-v4', myVersion='26.1.0', myPacking='aar',
>   myClassifier='null'} and
>   IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='androidx.documentfile',
>   myArtifactId='documentfile', myVersion='1.0.0', myPacking='aar',
>   myClassifier='null'} incompatible dependencies less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and
>   libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such
>   incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support
>   libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version
>   lower than your targetSdkVersion).  Issue id: GradleCompatible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have both AndroidX libraries and Support libraries together

You need to migrate to **AndroidX**

Go to **Refactor** -> **Migrate to AndroidX** -> **Migrate**

Your **build.gradle** file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "naik.dattaraj.meme2"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //AndroidX libraries
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.leanback:leanback:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    //Navigation
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.1'
    //firebase
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:18.1.0'
    //databinding
    implementation 'androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:3.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.databinding:databinding-common:3.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.databinding:adapters:3.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.databinding:databinding-adapters:3.3.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.3.0'
    //Google play services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    //Other libraries
    implementation 'com.shitij.goyal:slide-button:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.github.shts:StoriesProgressView:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.pwittchen:swipe-rx2:0.3.0'
    implementation 'com.tomer:fadingtextview:2.5'
    implementation 'com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.8.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.0'
    //compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.4.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

This should work.........

Comment: My build.gradle error is completely gone. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**Second Error:**

The second error is because you're trying to use android with AndroidX dependencies. Mix dependencies doesn't work like this. You have to convert all the android dependencies to AndroidX. Which means you cannot use Android support libraries. You need to replace them with equivalent AndroidX libraries.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

Above dependencies need to be changed to AndroidX equivalent.

**First Error:**

The first error is because you're using the `CircleImageView` source directly and it has not set `View.isInEditMode()`. Try following:

Replace this line:

```
implementation files('libs/CircleImageView-master/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar')
```

With this line:

```
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
```